# How to use Java to upload image, video and audio files to a database and also replacing them and updating the database?

Tags: java, image, audio, video

I am developing my first Java application and have been trying to implement every possible functionality I can. Here are my questions:

1. I have implemented jTable. The system loads the data from the database unto the jTable. When I click a row in the jTable or use my arrow keys, I am able to load the data from the selected row to the appropriate fields, edit and update the data. I am however, unable to update my database when I replace the existing image with a new one.
2. Suppose I also create columns for audio and video files in my database. How do I upload them to my database, make changes and update the database with the changes? I am able to do it with text, but my difficulty is with image, audio and video files.
   Hope to receive your brilliant contributions as usual.

The following are my codes:

I attached the following code to my Save button:

```
btnSave.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

              try{

                     String sql ="Insert into Counsellee (counselleeID,firstName,surname,address,telNo,gender,counsellorID,date,photo) values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";

                     pst=conn.prepareStatement(sql);
                     pst.setString(1, counselleeIDField.getText());
                     pst.setString(2, firstNameField.getText());
                     pst.setString(3, surnameField.getText());
                     pst.setString(4, addressField.getText());
                     pst.setString(5, TelField.getText());
                     String value=genderComboBox.getSelectedItem().toString();
                     pst.setString(6,value);
                     pst.setString(7, counsellorIDField.getText());
                     pst.setString(8, ((JTextField)transdateChooser.getDateEditor().getUiComponent()).getText());
                     pst.setBytes(9, person_image);
                     pst.execute();

                     /*
                      * To clear input fields for the next entry
                      */
                     counselleeIDField.setText("");
                     firstNameField.setText("");
                     surnameField.setText("");
                     addressField.setText("");
                     TelField.setText("");
                     genderComboBox.setSelectedItem("");
                     counsellorIDField.setText("");
                     /*I want to return the date field to the current date and clear the image selection path for the next image, but I
                      * have no idea how to go about it. 
                      */

                      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Saved");
                        }        

                       catch(Exception e)
                {
                       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);

                }
                   Update_table();
                   try {
                    pst.close();
                    rs.close();
                } catch (SQLException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
        }
    });
```

I attached the following codes to my Update button:

```
btnUpdateCounsellee.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

            try{

                String value1= counselleeIDField.getText();
                 String value2= firstNameField.getText();
                  String value3= surnameField.getText();
                  String value4= addressField.getText();
                  String value5= TelField.getText();
                  String value6=genderComboBox.getSelectedItem().toString();
                  String value7 =counsellorIDField.getText();
                  java.util.Date value8 = transdateChooser.getDate();
                  byte[] value9 = person_image.toString().getBytes(); //something seems wrong with this line as it is not converting my image as BLOB.
                                                                      //This is where my problem is.


                  String sql="update Counsellee set counselleeID='"+value1+"' ,firstName ='"+value2+"',surname ='"+value3+"',address='"+value4+"',telNo ='"+value5+"',gender ='"+value6+"',counsellorID ='"+value7+"',date ='"+value8+"',photo ='"+value9+"' where counselleeID='"+value1+"' ";
                  pst=conn.prepareStatement(sql);
                  pst.execute();

                 /*
                  * clear input fields for next action                        
                  */
                  counselleeIDField.setText("");
                    firstNameField.setText("");
                    surnameField.setText("");
                    addressField.setText("");
                    TelField.setText("");
                    genderComboBox.setSelectedItem("");
                    //I want to set date to current date here again

                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Updated");

            }catch(Exception e){

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);


            }
            Update_table();
            try {
                pst.close();
                rs.close();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
```

When I click update, the system actually uploads everything to the database, including the image. But the image does not save as BLOB, so I can't view it.

Comment: What DB are you using? Can you confirm the DB table structure?
For BLOBs, the usual case is that you need to insert the row, and then obtain a Stream to that column, and stream the data into it.

Comment: @Crollster I am using SQLite